# Libgdx stage add actor low FPS

Tags: android, kotlin, libgdx

I'm using ApplicationAdapter. When I have the code below in create() method, my fps is always about 14.

```
for (i in 0..1000) {
                stage.addActor(Food(
                        Food.TEXTURE_PURPLE!!,
                        100f,
                        (random.nextInt(MAP_SIZE)).toFloat(),
                        (random.nextInt(MAP_SIZE)).toFloat()))

                stage.addActor(Food(
                        Food.TEXTURE_GREEN!!,
                        100f,
                        (random.nextInt(MAP_SIZE)).toFloat(),
                        (random.nextInt(MAP_SIZE)).toFloat()))
}
```

But when I have this in create() method, my fps is always 60. Why?

```
    for (i in 0..1000) {
                stage.addActor(Food(
                        Food.TEXTURE_PURPLE!!,
                        100f,
                        (random.nextInt(MAP_SIZE)).toFloat(),
                        (random.nextInt(MAP_SIZE)).toFloat()))
            }

   for (i in 0..1000) {
              stage.addActor(Food(
                        Food.TEXTURE_GREEN!!,
                        100f,
                        (random.nextInt(MAP_SIZE)).toFloat(),
                        (random.nextInt(MAP_SIZE)).toFloat()))
            }
```

Comment: Can you clarify? You said it was in your `create()` method both times.

Comment: @Tenfour04 When I have only one loop in my oncreate I have 14 fps, but if I have 2 loops altogether in oncreate it is 60

Comment: Try logging `stage.root.children.size` for the two different cases. But 2000 actors sounds like a lot. Stage is mainly meant for UI or very simple games, in my opinion. It doesn't provide a way to avoid calling `draw()` on all the actors that are outside the view frustum, for example.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I've just done it and in both cases I had 2003. If 2000 actors is a lot why it works perfectly in the second case? The second problem I have is that when I add lets say blue actors to the stage using Timer.Task() every 0.1sec it works very well. Even every 0.01 second. But if I add 2 actors every 0.1sec that have 2 different colors my fps starts slowly falling to 1 fps. According to profiler my memory usage doesn't change but CPU even after all actors are added is still used by 14% but if I add actors that have the same color (even 5000), my CPU is always used by 5-6%.

Comment: Can you show your Food class? Maybe something you're doing is making it do more work when a food property doesn't match that of the previous child. When I say 2000 is kind of a lot, I mean I could see that becoming an issue on low end phones. Or if you have other actors to add as you get farther in developing your game.

Comment: @Tenfour04 https://drive.google.com/open?id=15Te9BV-gdeQDFTlGB0mw0neWKuSJ8DBk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is texture swapping. The way SpriteBatch works is you submit items to draw into its queue using one of its `draw` functions. Once you add something that can't be drawn with everything else in the queue, it flushes the queue by making an OpenGL draw call, and then it starts a new queue.

Two different textures cannot be drawn in the same OpenGL draw call, so when your Food items are not sorted by texture, each one of them is triggering another flush. Flushes are an expensive operation an you want to avoid having more than a few dozen.

The solution to this is to use a TextureAtlas, which combines multiple images into a single Texture, accessed via TextureRegion. You can submit TextureRegions to `SpriteBatch.draw(...)`. Many items with different TextureRegions can be drawn in a single batch queue so long as the TextureRegions share the same Texture.

On a side note...I strongly advise against using static references to Textures. The most commonly asked libgdx question on here is "why are my textures black" and it's always because they were using static texture references without understanding exactly how to dispose of the textures and reload properly. Static references outlive your game when on Android, which can cause big memory leaks, and bizarre bugs if you do any lazy loading of anything, which is very easy to accidentally do when using static references.

A cleaner design is to have one Assets class (maybe one for each stage if there is a lot of unique stuff per stage in your game) that has an AssetManager for loading all your stuff. A single assets instance can be passed to all your game object constructors. For example:

```
class Assets: Disposable {
    private val assetManager = AssetManager()

    lateinit val foodGreenTexture: Texture
    lateinit val foodRedTexture: Texture
    lateinit val foodBlueTexture: Texture
    //...

    init {
        assetManager.load("green.png", Texture::class.java)
        assetManager.load("red.png", Texture::class.java)
        //...
        assetManager.finishLoading()
        foodGreenTexture = assetManager.get("green.png")
        //...
    }

    override fun dispose (){
        assetManager.dispose()
    }
}
```

Don't forget to call dispose on your Assets class in the same object that initializes it (your game or screen).

I'll also suggest looking into using the CoveTools library which has a helper called AssignmentAssetManager that cuts out a bunch of the above boilerplate. The same class would look like this. Note how the `init` block will be super short, no matter how many different assets you are loading:

```
class Assets: Disposable {
    private val assetManager = AssignmentAssetManager()

    @Asset("green.png") val foodGreenTexture: Texture = null
    @Asset("red.png") val foodRedTexture: Texture = null
    @Asset("blue.png") val foodBlueTexture: Texture = null
    //...

    init {
        assetManager.loadAssetFields(this)
        assetManager.finishLoading()
    }

    override fun dispose (){
        assetManager.dispose()
    }
}
```

And a second side note... I strongly advise against using the Sprite class, especially when using Actors. Use the TextureRegion class instead. Sprite is a highly specialized class that extends TextureRegion but includes extra data like position, size, rotation, etc. This extra data is redundant if you are using Actor, so it's just error prone and a waste of CPU and memory to have to copy the data back and forth.

Comment: Thank you so much!